# app stuck on load time and take too much time to load

Tags: time, load

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sm.apps.studio.crawlervpn
this is link of my app my app starts well but stucks on splash screen i build this app in android studio please can you guide me how to fix this issue?

i published my app on google play store when i run my own app by downloading  it will get stuck on splash screen but when i run before publishing using apk file for testing it was run fine but now it will get stuck on splash screen how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your app uses a defective version of the OpenSSL library, which can cause your app to crash. Update to a fixed version of OpenSSL.

Defective versions:

OpenSSL 1.1.1g in lib/x86_64/libopenvpn.so

Comment: how can i update defective version of open ssl please help